# 4 x 2 button keypad in Swift Programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I developed it and its working properly on portrait mode but images are stretching in landscape, I inserted buttons in horizontal stack view, any solution to fix it.

```
let subStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttonArray)
subStackView.axis = .Horizontal

subStackView.distribution = .FillEqually
subStackView.alignment = .Fill
subStackView.spacing = 40
```

Comment: `subStackView.spacing = 40` - Remove this and provide equal spacing.
`subStackView.distribution = .EqualSpacing`

Comment: @vignesh Thank you i will try it

Comment: @Vignesh thank you its working

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
subStackView.distribution = .EqualSpacing
```

Comment: its working but in landscape mode centre having more space and buttons are getting smaller any option pls

Comment: Add a  aspect ratio constrain for the buttons.